# How to run program on remote computer via WMI using credentials that are differ from WMI scope

Tags: c#, wmi

I would like to run program using Win32_Process Create method, credential that I supply to Wmi connection is admin credentials, but program should be running under another credentials (non-admin, no access to WMI)

The only solution that I come up with is to run small program on computer that will impersonate to weaker user and will do the job, I think there should be the better way.

Answer (score 0):

Providing your logged on as admin, it shouldn't matter.

Example:

```
C:\>wmic process call create "cmd /c tasklist | sort & pause"
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 5240;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

Just make sure the command you execute is valid:

```
C:\>wmic process call create /?
Call                    [ In/Out ]Params&type                   Status
====                    =====================                   ======
Create                  [IN ]CommandLine(string)                Implemented

                        [IN ]CurrentDirectory(string)

                        [IN ]ProcessStartupInformation(object:Win32_ProcessStartup)

                        [OUT]ProcessId(uint32)

                        [OUT]ReturnValue(uint32)
```